# Como retornar imagem do DataSnap Server e mostrar no browser

Tags: delphi, web-service, rest, datasnap

Desenvolvi uma aplicação feita em `Web Service REST`, a onde é consumido os dados a cada requisição do cliente, tudo funciona perfeitamente, criei o `Web Service REST` a partir do `DataSnap REST Application`, com isso fica disponível um form para determinar a porta que vou usar, porém tive que migrar essa aplicação para um `Serviço`, o retorno da imagem não funcionou com a mesma função que eu uso na aplicação do `Web Service REST`, posso retornar a imagem em `png/jpeg`. Criei esse serviço a partir do `DataSnap Server`, incluindo a biblioteca `JavaScript`. 
Vou postar o fonte de como faço para retornar a imagem no `Web Service REST`:

```
oFileStream:= TFileStream.Create(sCaminho, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  if oFileStream.Size > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, oFileStream.Size);
    oFileStream.Read(Pointer(Result)^, oFileStream.Size);
  end;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(oFileStream);
end;

s := CarregarImagem(sCaminho);
GetInvocationMetadata(True).ResponseContentType := 'image/png';
GetInvocationMetadata(True).ResponseCode := 200;
GetInvocationMetadata(True).ResponseContent := s;
GetInvocationMetadata(True).CloseSession    := True;
```

Espero ter sido claro. Abraços!

Comment: Pelo que vi você não está trabalhando com `Encode64`. Tente criptografar a imagem e fazer um cliente para decodificar.

Comment: @Andrey, vou fazer isso, valeu pela dica

Comment: @Andrey, consegui resolver convertendo a imagem para base64 e testei na aplicação Postman, vou usar a base64 pois é a padrão ao mandar imagens para o cliente ler e visualizar.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho uma dúvida sobre esse tema. Tenho o seguinte código funcionando no delphi XE8:

```
foto := 'teste.jpg';

  if  FileExists(foto) then
  begin

    lStm := TStringStream.Create;
    lStm.LoadFromFile(foto);

    GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContentType := 'image/jpeg';
    GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContent := lStm.DataString;

    lStm.free;
  end;
```

isso gera a seguinte imagem:

[image: Código funcionando perfeitamente no XE8]

Observei também que o Content Type dele gerado é

[image: ContentType (via postman)]

Porém, no Tokyo 10.2, o mesmo código gera a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E o seguinte content Type
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Porque o mesmo código não funciona no Delphi mais novo ? É um BUG da versão nova? Ou tem que passar algum parâmetro a mais para que ele formate bem a imagem ?

Tentei fazer no tokyo 10.2 o seguinte para "forçar" pegar o mesmo contentType que era enviado no XE8, mas sem sucesso:

**`GetInvocationMetadata().ResponseContentType := 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, image/jpeg';`**

[image: como podem ver, ele não pega o image/jpeg]

Alguém já passou por esse problema ?

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente na transmissão de imagens via `REST`, é usado a `base64` para encriptar a imagem. Transmissão em `base64` é muito mais leve, pois não guarda informações em `cache`.